# Sending JSON object from flutter to PHP containing null values. php assum it as "null" string

Tags: php, flutter

if I send a JSON from flutter for example {'a':1,'b':null,'c':2}. using the below function. where (data) is the json object.

```
Future<String> sendData(Map data) async
  {

 http.Response response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
        body: jsonEncode(data));
if(response.statusCode==200)
  return (response.body);
else
  return 'No Data';

  }
```

php deal with null values as it's a word 'null' not null value. I used strlen($jsonObj['b']) it return 4. so how to check if the JSON key 'b' is null value without doing the following conditional.

```
if($jsonObj['b']=='null') // ..........working
   somecode;
```

I used

```
if($jsonObj['b']==null)
   somecode; // .......... not working (Note: null it's without single colon ' )
```

I used

```
if(empty($jsonObj['b']))
   somecode; // .......... not working
```

Answer (score 0):

Well then I suggest using `str_replace` to replace the `"null"` value with `""`.

Edit:

I looked at your code today and your problem may be caused by something else php is working fine.

check this link

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/191269dc04174cec34c9e5176fd89cf97e1d704e

Comment: it's not optimal solution. what if a user enter null as password

Comment: Thank you for the effort. but the data sent from the flutter app is JSON not JSON string.

Comment: I am sorry my bad. Thank you.